# Why did I my column names change to numbers when I did not assign them?

Tags: python, pandas

My code looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('FlightDistanceTest.csv')
df.rename(columns={'Normalised City Pair': 'destination'}, inplace=True)
split_city = df['destination'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
df = pd.concat([df, split_city], axis=1)
df.columns = list(range(len(df.columns)))
```

The original df looked like this but with the code above, I was able to split the airport column by the - so that the cities were split into 2 new columns and then I concatenated them to the original df. My issue is.. ALL the columns names have been changed to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.. which I did not assign.Even when I save it to a csv, the column names are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in excel... what did I do wrong? Thanks

```
old_index   destination                                 arr dep
0   319         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
1   320         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
2   321         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
3   322         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
4   323         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
5   324         Dusseldorf, Germany - Paris, France     CDG DUS
6   325         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
7   326         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
8   327         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
9   328         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
10  329         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I copy and pasted the code which worked great (except for the column name change) but from what I understand, the Len function is measuring the length of the columns (which is 5),  then the range is taking the range of columns (0:5), then list converts it to a list? How would I change my code so that I retain my original column names?

Comment: Yep, you have that exactly right. If you're happy with the column names prior to that step, then just deleting that line is enough to give you want you want. Otherwise, you can change it to rename them to something else.

Answer (score 1):

just delete the last row.

`df.columns = list(range(len(df.columns)))` changes your column names to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use last line code -

```
df.columns = list(range(len(df.columns)))
```

This will rename your DataFrame columns to 0,1,2,3,.....